# Automake/Autoconf scripts custom directory

Tags: makefile, automake, autoconf

My project's root folder is `PROJECT`, and there is only one script in `PROJECT/scripts/abc.sh`, which I want to install it into the directory `/usr/share/xxx/abc.sh`.

Because it is not install into `/usr/bin/abc.sh`, so `bin_SCRIPTS = abc.sh` is incorrect.

Could you please tell me how to write the `Makefile.am`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define the install directory:

```
xxxdir = $(datarootdir)/xxx

xxx_SCRIPTS = scripts/abc.sh
```

[More typically](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Scripts.html#index-SCRIPTS_002c-installation-directories) as something like:

```
pkgdata_SCRIPTS = scripts/abc.sh
```

where automake has already setup `pkgdatadir`.